# Call to a member function links() on array in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using pagination in Laravel 5.6 to build an application. I am using Laravel DB instead of Eloquent. However, when I add a pagination link on view, it shows an error **Call to a member function links() on array**. This is because I am using an array, the default is an object with a collection. The output I am getting looks like

```
array:12 [▼
    "current_page" => 1
    "data" => array:3 [▶]
    "first_page_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts?page=1"
    "from" => 1
    "last_page" => 3
    "last_page_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts?page=3"
    "next_page_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts?page=2"
    "path" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts"
    "per_page" => 3
    "prev_page_url" => null
    "to" => 3
    "total" => 9
]
```

When I use normal pagination i.e. without converting to an array, the output is

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#264 ▼
    #total: 9
    #lastPage: 3
    #items: Collection {#251 ▶}
    #perPage: 3
    #currentPage: 1
    #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts"
    #query: []
    #fragment: null
    #pageName: "page"
}
```

The problem I face here is adding other data to collection

I can't use the default output return by pagination() method. Can someone please suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your view code and any controller code that might be relevant as well.

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please explain it again?

Comment: Please show us the code which creates the pagination object (usually it is in a controller class) and the code which adds the pagination link to the HTML code (usually it is in a view template).

Comment: Inside view I used $page->links() to show the pagination. Used toArray() to convert collection of object to an array

Comment: adding what other data to collection?

Comment: Other data means my actual project data

Answer (score 1):

Using the below, I am getting the required output. 
Step 1: Include LengthAwarePaginator in the file

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

Step 2: Create an object of LengthAwarePaginator

```
$paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator(Array, countOfArray, perPage, currentPage, [
        'path' =>  request()->url(),
        'query' => request()->query()
]);
```

I kept currentPage value as null.
Return $paginate to view.

```
return view('home', ['data' => Array, 'page' => $paginate]);
```